# Adding users to groups with gpasswd and useremod

Tags: command-line

what is the difference between doing

`sudo usermod -a -G docker User_name`

and

`sudo gpasswd -a User_name docker`

it seems both add a user to a group (in this case "docker")

Answer (score 3):

No difference. They're just doing it from different perspectives:

- `usermod` is operating on a user. Its main argument is the username.
- `gpasswd` is operating on a group. Its main argument is the group name.

Aside from that, IMO `usermod` has greater potential for damage. If you forgot the `-a` option, it will remove the user from *all* other groups and make it a member of only the `docker` group. With `gpasswd`, at worst you add or remove the user from one group.